# Win CMD: How to escape "=" in string substitution

Tags: windows, command-line, string-substitution

```
set "a=6=5"
echo %a%
6=5

echo "%a:6=5=6-5%"
"5=6-5=5"
```

should give me (the expected answer) `6-5` instead.

I've escaped `=` **after** expression to be replaced, but the `=` **in** the expression is treated by CMD as the delimiter of the substituent.

```
echo "%a:6=5^=6-5%"
"5^=6-5=5"

echo %a:"6=5"="6-5"%
6=5

echo %a:"6^=5"="6-5"%
6=5
```

How should I structure it to get `6-5` to replace `6=5`?

Comment: The only workaround I got is `for` loop with `=` delimiter

Answer (score 0):

Solution via `for` loop in last line. No delimit characters work for `=`:

```
for /f "delims==" %i in ('echo %a%') do echo %i
6 5
for /f "delims==" %i in ('echo %a%') do echo %i,
6 5,
for /f "delims=^=" %i in ('echo %a%') do echo %i,
6 5,
for /f "delims=\=" %i in ('echo %a%') do echo %i,
6 5,
for /f "delims===" %i in ('echo %a%') do echo %i,
6 5,
for /f "delims=`=" %i in ('echo %a%') do echo %i,
6 5,
for /f "delims=`=" %i in ('echo %a%') do set i=%i& echo !i: =-!
6-5
```